# Jquery Image Gallery - Sliding images on click

Tags: jquery, image, click, slide

I'm not very experienced in Jquery and seem to be having lots of problems with what I'm trying to accomplish. I have a bunch of images placed side by side (with overflow hidden) and when I click on the "next" button, the next image is supposed to appear and so on. A perfect example of what I'm trying to achieve would be what "mlb.com" is doing on their home page. They have about 10 different headlines and everytime you hit the next arrow, the next headline appears.

Comment: Try this - http://google.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get it done for a client, I would recommend just using something like the nivo slider http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/

Or if you're interested in learning just google jquery slider tutorial and you will find hundreds of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sliders may be it's help full for you.

```
http://wowslider.com/demo.html
```